# Are there any issues with deeply nested master pages in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I'm using ASP.NET nested master pages on my site, but I actually have more than one level of nesting.  All of the examples out there generally address a simple scenario of a single master page ("M") and several nested master pages ("A", "B", and "C") that derive from "M".

In my case, I'd really like to have many more deeply nested levels.

```
M => A => A1
M => A => A1 => X
M => A => A1 => Y
M => B => B1
M => B => B2
etc.
```

Is this the right way to organize my master pages? Are there any performance penalities to having deeply nested master pages?

Answer (score 3):

Your performance concerns should be outweighed by maintainability concerns.  The biggest drawback to this kind of spaghetti (in my opinion) is that other developers who are stuck maintaining this code will have to spend extra time trying to figure out what's going on.  Try to keep things relatively simple, so that any ASP.NET developer off the street can come in and easily pick up where you left off.

Also, under what scenario are you thinking of organizing your web application like this?  If an example of the business problem you're trying to address is provided, perhaps we can help offer up alternative solutions.

Comment: I wouldn't call this spaghetti at all. My scenario is that I want to have a single master page for shared elements, but I have lots of different flavors of pages on my site.

Comment: Some pages need to expose a login piece, other pages do not. Some pages need to have a "find" dialog, other pages do not.  I have lots of different flavors and lots of different combinations of flavors (e.g. base page, base + login, base + login + find, base + find, etc.). If I were doing this with C# classes, I'd make a base class and have other derived classes.  But it seems that ASP.NET only wants to have 1 level of interitance.  What I don't want to do is to have to duplicate a lot of code between different master page base pages.  IMO, doing **that** will lead to maintenance headaches.

Comment: It sounds like your main issue is regarding authorization/access.  Perhaps you should let each control determine its own visibility state.